# How to define custom number of ticks while using matplotilib.dates

Tags: python, matplotlib, time-series

I am trying to plot a time series using matplotlib.dates. I have achieved all required properties except the number of ticks on X-axis (Figure below). Currently there are 6 ticks and x-axis looks dense. I want to reduce number of ticks to 4. I am using below code.

[image]

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
font = {'family' : "Times New Roman",
       'weight' : 'bold',
       'size'   : 26}
plt.rc('font', **font)
rcParams['font.family'] = 'sans-serif'
rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = ['Times New Roman']
df = pd.DataFrame({'values':open},index=date)
fig,ax1 = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(8, 8)
plt.plot(df.index,df.values,color = 'black')
plt.ylabel('Stocks open')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.yticks(np.arange(0,50000.01,15000))
datemin = np.datetime64(date[0])
datemax = np.datetime64(date[-1])
ax1.set_xlim(datemin, datemax)
plt.gca().set_aspect('auto', adjustable='box')
monthyearFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d')
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(monthyearFmt)
_ = plt.xticks(rotation=60)
```

Comment: You can use the [LinearLocator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64957205/8881141).

Comment: A list of the tick locator types matplotlib provides can be [found here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/ticks_and_spines/tick-locators.html).

Comment: Thanks you very much. That solved a big problem for me.